# Is subprocess.Popen not thread safe?

Tags: python, concurrency, thread-safety, subprocess, popen

The following simple script hangs on the subprocess.Popen call intermittently (roughly 30% of the time).
Unless use_lock = True, and then it never hangs, leading me to believe subprocess is not thread safe!
The expected behavior is script finishes within 5-6 seconds.
To demonstrate the bug, just run "python bugProof.py" a few times until it hangs. Ctrl-C exits. You'll see the 'post-Popen' appear only once or twice but not the third time.

```
import subprocess, threading, fcntl, os, time
end_time = time.time()+5
lock = threading.Lock()
use_lock = False
path_to_factorial = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'factorial.sh')

def testFunction():
    print threading.current_thread().name, '| pre-Popen'
    if use_lock: lock.acquire()
    p = subprocess.Popen([path_to_factorial], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if use_lock: lock.release()
    print threading.current_thread().name, '| post-Popen'
    fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
    fcntl.fcntl(p.stderr, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
    while time.time()<end_time:
        try: p.stdout.read()
        except: pass
        try: p.stderr.read()
        except: pass
    print threading.current_thread().name, '| DONE'

for i in range(3):
    threading.Thread(target=testFunction).start()
```

The shell script referenced above (factorial.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Calculating factorial (anything that's somewhat compute intensive, this script takes 3 sec on my machine"
ans=1
counter=0
fact=999
while [ $fact -ne $counter ]
do
    counter=`expr $counter + 1`
    ans=`expr $ans \* $counter`
done
echo "Factorial calculation done"
read -p "Test input (this part is critical for bug to occur): " buf
echo "$buf"
```

System info:
Linux 2.6.32-358.123.2.openstack.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Sep 26 17:14:58 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2013, 11:34:30)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2

Comment: Putting close_fds=True in the Popen call also fixes the problem for some reason.

Comment: This was literally the most infuriating thing I've encountered in Python in recent times. Sooo frustrating.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Python 2.x, there are various race conditions affecting subprocess.Popen. (e.g. on 2.7 it disables & restores garbage collection to prevent various timing issues, but this is not thread-safe in itself). See e.g. http://bugs.python.org/issue2320, http://bugs.python.org/issue1336 and http://bugs.python.org/issue14548 for a few of the issues in this area.

A substantial revision to subprocess was made in Python 3.2 which addresses these (amongst other things, the fork & exec code is in a C module, rather than doing some reasonably involved Python code in the critical part between fork and exec), and is available backported to recent Python 2.x releases in the [subprocess32](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32/) module. Note the following from the PyPI page: "On POSIX systems it is guaranteed to be reliable when used in threaded applications."

I can reproduce the occasional (about 25% for me) crashes of the code above, but after using `import subprocess32 as subprocess` I've not seen any failures in 100+ runs.

Note that subprocess32 (and Python 3.2+) default to close_fds=True, but with subprocess32 in place, I saw no failures even with close_fds=False (not that you should generally need that).