# Is subprocess.Popen() expected to be threadsafe in python 3.x >= 3.2?

Tags: python, subprocess

From [Is subprocess.Popen not thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194380/is-subprocess-popen-not-thread-safe) it's clear that prior to 3.2, `subprocess.Popen()` had serious threading issues, and 3.2 improved the situation significantly. However, AFAICT the Python documents do not state one way or the other whether `subprocess` is currently thread safe or not. I'd like to chuck some `Popen()` invocations on a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (for executing shell commands which I need to send stdin to), but not if there's any potential for nasty concurrency surprises in doing so.

Is `subprocess.Popen()` thread safe now, or is it still appreciably dangerous?